# Data not writing to subdocuments in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using Node.js + Express for backend and MongoDB for database. My problem is that when I write data to the database, the subdocuments remain empty, i.e. I am not able to write data into the subdocuments.

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRlpI.png)

Fields employeeInformation up to cancellationReason  are all subdocuments. When I do a console.log of req.body, I can see that my fields are populated with the correct values, but in MongoDB and in the response, there is no data. I can also write fine using Postman.

Here is my app.post code:

```
// POST
app.post('/create-incident', (req, res) => {
  let incidentNumber = functions.createIncidentNumber();
  let status = 'New';

  const incidentHeader = new IncidentHeader({
    incidentNumber: incidentNumber,
    status: status,
    employeeInformation: req.body.employeeInformation,
    incidentDetail: req.body.incidentDetail,
    spi: req.body.spi,
    investigationDetail: req.body.investigationDetail,
    recommendation: req.body.recommendation,
    dataPrivacyDetail: req.body.dataPrivacyDetail,
    infrastructureDetail: req.body.infrastructureDetail,
    dataElement: req.body.dataElement,
    processIncident: req.body.processIncident,
    legislation: req.body.legislation,
    dataPrivacyEducation: req.body.dataPrivacyEducation,
    rca: req.body.rca,
    approval: req.body.approval,
    auditTrail: req.body.auditTrail,
    cancellationReason: req.body.cancellationReason
  });

  console.log(`req.body: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);

  incidentHeader
    .save()
    .then(IncidentHeader => {
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(IncidentHeader));
      console.log('Saved to IncidentHeader.');
    })
    .catch(e => {
      return res.status(400).send(e);
      console.log('Unable to save to IncidentHeader.');
    });
});
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Here is the link to my GitHub project should you wish to inspect the code further. Thank you in advance.

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jake2point0/wam-itair)

Comment: In MongoDB, what's the name of the collection you are querying to get the data inserted from your app?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but the collection name is `IncidentHeader`. The data input is purely from HTML input fields, so the data source is user entry.

Comment: I'm asking because of how Mongoose structures its models. When no collection argument is passed in your Mongoose model definition `Mongoose#model(name, [schema], [collection], [skipInit])`, it produces a collection name by pluralizing the model name. So in this case you may want to query the collection called `incidentheaders` which Mongoose produces by default

Comment: Oh, ok. Yes, I see the `incidentheaders` collection in my local DB.